# Python inheritance: modify a parent class of an object

Tags: python, inheritance, super

I need/want to modify a parent class and have problems with proper import. The child object still uses the "old" version of the class.

**File A** (some lib which I do not want to modify directly):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contentA = "42"
        print("A.__init__() ausgeführt")
    def m(self):
        print("A.m() aufgerufen")
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        #A.__init__(self)
        super().__init__()
        self.contentB = "43"
        print("B.__init__() ausgeführt")
    def m(self):
        #A.m(self)
        super().m()
        print("B.m() aufgerufen")
```

**File B**:

```
import somelib as demo

class A(demo.A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    def f(self):
        '''
        new function for A!
        '''
        print("A.f():", self.contentA)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = demo.B()
    b.m()
    print("b.contentB: " + str(b.contentB))
    print("b.contentA: " + str(b.contentA))
    b.f() # not found!
```

The newly added function f() is not found. How do I have to do this correctly?

Comment: Yeah, that's not how it works. `somelib.B` inherits from `somelib.A`, not from your `A`. Why don't you subclass `somelib.B` as your own `B` and add the method there?!

Comment: @deceze: I did that initially, but then I thought that overloading the original class A is "nicer" or better style. Have now learned it is not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because your class is *also* called `A` this doesn't mean that it will overwrite a previously defined class `A` in another module. Even if it would, the class `B` would not depend on it automatically.

Your problem is likely better solved by writing your inherited class `B` in this module, but if you really want to modify the parent class you can:

```
import somelib as demo

def f(self):
    '''
    new function for A!
    '''
    print("A.f():", self.contentA)

demo.A.f = f  # assign f to the f attribute of A

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = demo.B()
    b.m()
    print("b.contentB: " + str(b.contentB))
    print("b.contentA: " + str(b.contentA))
    b.f() # found!
```

Comment: As L3viathan alludes to, while you can do it this way, you really shouldn't as it violates the Open-Closed Principle.

Comment: Thank you! I'll include the new function in a modified class B then.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably monkey patching, e.g.:

```
import somelib as demo

def f(self):
    '''
    new function for A!
    '''
    print("A.f():", self.contentA)

demo.A.f = f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = demo.B()
    b.m()
    print("b.contentB: " + str(b.contentB))
    print("b.contentA: " + str(b.contentA))
    b.f() # should now be found!
```

Comment: Love it when you post the *identical* answer moments after someone else and get downvoted as a result. Really motivates you to spend time answering questions